# Number of Equation: 1, 1a, 1b

Tags: equations, amsmath, counters, subequations

Following Problem:
I have a PDE and two boundary conditions what i actually want is:

PDE (1)

BC1 (1a)

BC2 (1b)

and what i have is:

PDE (1)

BC1 (2a)

BC2 (2b)

is there something which provides a functionallity like this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[standalone]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \nonumber \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\widetilde{c}_{\text{s}}\left(r,z,t\right)+c_{\text{s,0}}\right)=\frac{D_{\text{s}}}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^{2}\frac{\partial \left(\widetilde{c}_{\text{s}}\left(r,z,t\right)+c_{\text{s,0}}\right)}{\partial r}\right)
\label{eq:litdiff}
\end{equation}
The boundary conditions of Eq. \eqref{eq:litdiff} are given by
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        D_{\text{s}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \widetilde{c}_{\text{s}}(0,z,t)&=0\label{eq:diffusionpartialdiff_boundaries0}\\
        D_{\text{s}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \widetilde{c}_{\text{s}}(R_{\text{s}},z,t) &= -j(z,t)\label{eq:diffusionpartialdiff_boundariesRs}
        \intertext{and the initial condition is given by}
        \widetilde{c}_{\text{s}}(r,z,0) = 0 \quad r\in \left[0;R_{\text{s}}\right]. \label{eq:diffusionpartialdiff_init}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to remove `\nonumber` in the main equation and use `\addtocounter{equation}{-1}` just before `\begin{subequations}`

Comment: `utf8x` option to `inputenc` is outdated, the `standalone` option has no effect to `article`

Comment: In fact you have PDEs, not ODEs...

Comment: \nonumber was a failure because of copy and paste; yes it's PDE...too focused on the Latex-Problem. i'll edit it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `\tag` and the fact that `\label` at the start of a `subequations` environment refers to the current main equation number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\subs}{\textup{s}}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:litdiff}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\widetilde{c}_{\subs}(r,z,t)+c_{\subs,0})=
  \frac{D_{\subs}}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
    \left(
      r^{2}\frac{\partial (\widetilde{c}_{\subs}(r,z,t)+c_{\subs,0})}{\partial r}
    \right)
\tag{\ref{eq:litdiff}}
\end{equation}
The boundary conditions of Eq.~\eqref{eq:litdiff} are given by
\begin{align}
D_{\subs}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \widetilde{c}_{\subs}(0,z,t)
  &=0\label{eq:diffusionpartialdiff_boundaries0}\\
D_{\subs}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \widetilde{c}_{\subs}(R_{\subs},z,t)
  &= -j(z,t)\label{eq:diffusionpartialdiff_boundariesRs}
\end{align}
and the initial condition is given by
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{c}_{\subs}(r,z,0) = 0 \quad r\in [0;R_{\subs}]. 
  \label{eq:diffusionpartialdiff_init}
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

I removed all the superfluous `\left` and `\right`. Also `\text{s}` has been changed to `\subs` for better readability and input (note that `_{\text{s,0}}` is wrong and should be `_{\text{s},0}`).

The last equation needs `equation`, not being in the `align`.

**Important.** Don't forget `~` in cases such as `Eq.~\eqref{eq:litdiff}`.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A `\addtocounter{equation}{-1}` will do. However, I don't get the `nonumber` directive in a equation you refer to later, so I deleted it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\widetilde{c}_{\text{s}}\left(r,z,t\right)+c_{\text{s,0}}\right)=\frac{D_{\text{s}}}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^{2}\frac{\partial \left(\widetilde{c}_{\text{s}}\left(r,z,t\right)+c_{\text{s,0}}\right)}{\partial r}\right)
\label{eq:litdiff}
\end{equation}
The boundary conditions of Eq. \eqref{eq:litdiff} are given by\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        D_{\text{s}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \widetilde{c}_{\text{s}}(0,z,t)&=0\label{eq:diffusionpartialdiff_boundaries0}\\
        D_{\text{s}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \widetilde{c}_{\text{s}}(R_{\text{s}},z,t) &= -j(z,t)\label{eq:diffusionpartialdiff_boundariesRs}
        \intertext{and the initial condition is given by}
        \widetilde{c}_{\text{s}}(r,z,0) = 0 \quad r\in \left[0;R_{\text{s}}\right]. \label{eq:diffusionpartialdiff_init}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

From condition \eqref{eq:diffusionpartialdiff_boundaries0}, we see that…

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Personally, I think this one is a little cleaner than the OP's preferred answer.  And it seems less "hack"-y to me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for equations with a number greater than 1.