# Subequations with main equation number

Tags: equations, subequations

I would like to have a set of equations, all under the same number, but with a "main" equation, and some other equations that follow being labelled with subnumbers, for example

> 1 = 1              (1)
>
> 1 < 2              (1a)
>
> 1 > 0              (1b)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220001/number-of-equation-1-1a-1b there are a few methods to achiev this. Have a look!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `\tag` for getting the main number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{first:main}
First some separate equations
\begin{equation}
1=1 \tag{\ref{first:main}}
\end{equation}
and another
\begin{equation}
1>0 \label{first:a}
\end{equation}
and another
\begin{equation}
1<2 \label{first:b}
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}\label{second:main}
But it works also with \texttt{align} and the other alignment
environments
\begin{align}
1 &= 1 \tag{\ref{second:main}}\\
1 &> 0 \label{second:a}\\
1 &< 2 \label{second:b}
\end{align}
and you can reference all of them, as seen below.
\end{subequations}

Here are some references: \eqref{first:main}, \eqref{first:a}
and \eqref{second:b}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had seen the tag command but could not use it properly - I see here in this case you are passing it a reference to the label for the entire subequation structure.

Comment: If you are using the [tag:hyperref] environment, the solution should be modified to `\tag{\ref*{first:main}}` to avoid the label to show up as a possibly colored hyperlink.