# How to reference long equations by numbered alphabets

Tags: equations, align, subequations

I have 2 long equations when I want to label them as 2a and 2b by using `subequation` a problem occur that each line of equation n pdf gets number inspite of each equation so thats why i got more numbering than no. of equations

```
 \begin{subequations} \label{eq2}
 \begin{align}
 \ddot{x} & = \big( \cos{\phi} \sin{\theta} \cos{\psi} + \sin{\phi} \sin{\psi} \big) \frac{U_1}{m}\\ & \quad - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{4} H_{xi} - K_{fdx} \frac{\dot{x}}{m_s}\\

 \ddot{y} & = \big( \cos{\phi} \sin{\theta} \sin{\psi} - \sin{\phi} \sin{\psi} \big) \frac{U_1}{m}\\ & \quad- \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{4} H_{yi} - K_{fdy} \frac{\dot{y}}{m_s}\\
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

[image: output looks like this while i wana output equations to be labeled just 2a for x double dot equation and 2b for y double dot equation]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225520/14757

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

[image]

Above equation is obtained by:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq2}
    \begin{align}
\ddot{x} & = \begin{multlined}[t]
            \big(\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}\cos{\psi} + 
                 \sin{\phi}\sin{\psi}\big) 
                 \frac{U_1}{m}\\ 
               - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{4} H_{xi} - K_{fdx} \frac{\dot{x}}{m_s}
            \end{multlined}    \\
\ddot{y} & = \begin{multlined}[t]
            \big(\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}\sin{\psi} - 
                  \sin{\phi}\sin{\psi}\big) \frac{U_1}{m}\\ 
               - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{4} H_{yi} - K_{fdy} \frac{\dot{y}}{m_s}
            \end{multlined}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: yeah i mean the way u did in 2nd phase 
actually i cannot manage to write equations in single line as i am doing for a research paper 2 column format so it becomes too wide if i dont use multiple lines environment.
Thankx for ur answer

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three possibilities.

- Don't split the equations across lines;
- Use `\notag` on two of the four rows of the `align` environment;
- Use two `split` environments within the overall `align` environment.

The first solution looks like it's the simplest overall. Choosing between solutions 2 and 3 will depend, in part, on whether or not the equation numbers should be centered on each of the pairs of rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{subequations} \label{eq2}
\begin{align}
\ddot{x} 
&= \big( \cos{\phi} \sin{\theta} \cos{\psi} + \sin{\phi} \sin{\psi} \big) \frac{U_1}{m} - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{4} H_{xi} - K_{fdx} \frac{\dot{x}}{m_s}\\
\ddot{y} 
&= \big( \cos{\phi} \sin{\theta} \sin{\psi} - \sin{\phi} \sin{\psi} \big) \frac{U_1}{m} - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{4} H_{yi} - K_{fdy} \frac{\dot{y}}{m_s}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\hrule
\begin{subequations} \label{eq4}
\begin{align}
\ddot{x} 
&= \big( \cos{\phi} \sin{\theta} \cos{\psi} + \sin{\phi} \sin{\psi} \big) \frac{U_1}{m} \notag\\
&\qquad - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{4} H_{xi} - K_{fdx} \frac{\dot{x}}{m_s}\\
\ddot{y} 
&= \big( \cos{\phi} \sin{\theta} \sin{\psi} - \sin{\phi} \sin{\psi} \big) \frac{U_1}{m} \notag\\
&\qquad - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{4} H_{yi} - K_{fdy} \frac{\dot{y}}{m_s}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\hrule
\begin{subequations} \label{eq4}
\begin{align}
&\begin{split}\ddot{x} 
  &= \big( \cos{\phi} \sin{\theta} \cos{\psi} + \sin{\phi} \sin{\psi} \big) \frac{U_1}{m} \\
  &\qquad - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{4} H_{xi} - K_{fdx} \frac{\dot{x}}{m_s}
\end{split}\\
&\begin{split}
\ddot{y} &= \big( \cos{\phi} \sin{\theta} \sin{\psi} - \sin{\phi} \sin{\psi} \big) \frac{U_1}{m} \\
&\qquad - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{4} H_{yi} - K_{fdy} \frac{\dot{y}}{m_s}
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\hrule
\end{document}
```