# How to set equation counter as three to the power "a"

Tags: setcounter

I want my counter to look like this: [image: a]

```
\setcounter{equation}{3^a}
%and
\setcounter{equation}{$3^a$}
%doesnt work
```

OR maybe Im wrong and thats not counter
[image]

Comment: counters can only be integers. You nedd to do it sowhat manually `\tag{$\thesection^{\mathrm{a}}$}` (untested)

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225517/subequations-with-main-equation-number?noredirect=1&lq=1 which is a bit simpler.

Comment: @Marijn LOVE YA. THAT ONE WILL PASS THE EXAM

Comment: See also `\textsuperscript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

----> set equation counter as three to the power "a".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\setcounter{equation}{2}\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}$^{\textup a}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \Delta=b^2-4ac
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, your code is exactly the same. you got my respect

Comment: @DScounterGO You are welcome. :-)