# change subequations labelling to '1.1'

Tags: amsmath, subequations

Similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225517/subequations-with-main-equation-number) question, how can I get the `subequations` environment to give me `number.number` style labels, e.g., labels like `1.1` and `1.2`? How can I do so locally (i.e., not for the entire document)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Locally

Just put `\def\theequation{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}%` after `\begin{subequations}`.

[image]

## Globally

Put the code below after `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{subequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  % \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks for this!

Answer (score 6):

(edited answer to address OP's follow-up request)

You could use the command `\patchcmd`, which is provided by the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package, to "patch" the `\subequations` macro of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package:

```
\patchcmd\subequations{\alph{equation}}{.\arabic{equation}}{}{}
```

Put this command in the preamble to make the change global. If you want to keep the change local to a particular instance of a `subequations` environment, I suggest you enclose the patching command shown above and the `subequations` environment of interest in a TeX group, e.g., via

```
\begingroup
\patchcmd\subequations{\alph{equation}}{.\arabic{equation}}{}{}
\begin{subequations}
...
\end{subequations}
\endgroup
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for 'subequations' environment
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % for '\patchcmd' macro
% the scope of the following instruction is *global*
\patchcmd\subequations{\alph{equation}}{.\arabic{equation}}{}{}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
  a+b=c \\ 
  d+e=f 
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: great! If I want to only do this for some `subequations` environments, but not all, do I simply put the `\patchcmd\subequations{\alph{equation}}{.\arabic{equation}}{}{}` call in the desired `subequations` environment?

Comment: @rrrrr - The `\subequations` command has to be patched *before* executing `\begin{subequations}`.  (Basically, upon entering the `subequations` *environment*, LaTeX executes `\subequations` *macro; upon leaving the `subequations` environment, LaTeX executes `\endsubequations`.) I'd therefore use something like `\begingroup \patchcmd\subequations{\alph{equation}}{.\arabic{equation}}{}{} \begin{subequations} ... \end{subequations} \endgroup` to localize the change to a particular `subequations` environment.

Comment: Great! WOuld you mind putting this in your answer? I've modified the question for future people in case they would like the option of doing local changes

Comment: @rrrrr - Please see the edit I've applied.