# \ref and \nameref with alpha enumerated items

Tags: cross-referencing, enumitem

Is there a way to keep the enumeration list with **(a)**, **(b)**, etc., and have references provide the complete context like **1.1.1(a)**?

[image]

The section and sub-section references display as I’d like with **1.1** and **1.1.1** and the name-references works as well, **“First”** and **“And..”**. The enumerated item reference shows as **28** but I'd like **1.1.1(ab)**. And the enumerated item name-reference is wrong (**“Also..”**), though perhaps that’s intentional. So, the enumerated alpha item reference has two issues: it doesn’t include it’s context; and, it doesn’t honor the enumeration alpha display characteristics.
For my use, a custom command for the references is fine but the command hopefully won't require both the subsection and the item labels, e.g., instead of writing the verbose and error-prone:

**`\myuglyitemref{subsec:first-and}{itm:faab}`**

is there some way to define a reference so I can write:

**`\myawesomeitemref{itm:faab}`**

which displays **1.1.1(ab)**?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter
\def\enumalphalphcnt#1{\expandafter\@enumalphalphcnt\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@enumalphalphcnt#1{\alphalph{#1}}
\makeatother
\AddEnumerateCounter{\enumalphalphcnt}{\@enumalphalphcnt}{aa}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\enumalphalphcnt{enumi})}
% my (ugly) item reference
\newcommand{\myuglyitemref}[2]{\ref{#1}\labelenumi}
\begin{document}
\chapter{SOMETHING}The chapter.
\section{First}\label{sec:first}
Section items show with (ab) but referenced with 1.1(ab)
\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{27}
\item {First 28} \label{itm:fab} 28th element
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{And...}\label{subsec:first-and}
Subsection items show with (a) but referenced with 1.1.1(a)
\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{27}
\item {And 28} \label{itm:faab} 28th element
\end{enumerate}
Correct: \ref{sec:first} and \ref{subsec:first-and}
Correct: ``\nameref{sec:first}'' and ``\nameref{subsec:first-and}''
Incorrect: \ref{itm:fab} and \ref{itm:faab} - should be 1.1(ab) and 1.1.1(ab)
Incorrect: ``\nameref{itm:faab}''
Ugly: \myuglyitemref{subsec:first-and}{itm:faab}
```

Comment: You can put almost anything into a \ref (like pgfplot legends).  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236626/refer-to-the-name-of-an-equation-while-a-list-of-equations-is-generated-using/237126?s=14|0.0000#237126 for example.

Comment: `enumitem` lets you specify the label and cross-reference separately for all ordered lists, custom ordered lists, this ordered list, this series of ordered lists, whatever. `fancyref` and/or `cleverref` might also be of interest.

Comment: Why are you loading `enumitem` and not using it to make life easier?!

Comment: I'm a big fan of easy, @cfr, especially if it solves my problem. ;-) I certainly meant to use the `enumitem` package in the _preamble_ but I'm a beginner so perhaps I misused it -- how should the _preamble_ be modified enable a document-wide change to `enumerate` to use alpha?

Comment: The `\ref` is very flexible, @JohnKormylo -- but can I, somehow, derive the _environment_ within `\ref` so I could write something like `\myref{itm:faab}`?

Comment: **That's the magic sauce, @cfr!** Want to answer with this so I can give you credit, or would you like me to answer it on your behalf?

Comment: I can put it in an answer but it is not right. It does not give the results you want. It is closer than what you have. But it is not right.

Comment: Right -- the `\subsection` works as I want, but the `\section` has an extra **.0**.

Comment: Partial solution posted...

Comment: Actually, \ref just writes out whatever \label stores in the aux file.  \label is the one doing all the work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer addresses only the cross-referencing of enumerated items, where the appearance of the cross-referenced "numbers" depends on whether the items occur at the section level or the subsection level. (Aside: This site "works" best if postings contain *only one major question* at a time. That's why I'm not even trying to address the other major question you've raised, viz., how to use `\nameref` on the "titles" of enumerated items.)

The solution works by modifying the low-level LaTeX macros `\theenumi`, `\labelenumi`, and `\p@enumi`. Observe the use of an `\ifnum` conditional in the statement that modifies the `\p@enumi` macro.

In the example below, the `hyperref` package is loaded merley to highlight which parts of the typeset text are the actual cross-references generated by `\ref` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\renewcommand\theenumi{(\alphalph{\value{enumi}})}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumi{\ifnum\value{subsection}=0{\thesection}\else{\thesubsection}\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} %% just for this example

\begin{document}
\chapter{SOMETHING}
The chapter.

\section{First section}\label{sec:first}

Section-level enumerated items: Labels should show as ``(ab)'' and should be cross-referenced as ``1.1(ab)''.

\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{27}
\item 28th element \label{itm:fab} 
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{First subsection}\label{subsec:first-and}
Section-level enumerated items: Labels should show as ``(ba)'' and should be cross-referenced as ``1.1.1(ba)''.

\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{52}
\item 53rd element \label{itm:faab} 
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Second subsection}

Correct: Section \ref{sec:first} and subsection \ref{subsec:first-and} \dots

\medskip\noindent
Now also correct: Items \ref{itm:fab} and \ref{itm:faab} \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JanNielsen - You're welcome! :-) Incidentally, while the `nameref` package extracts sectioning names for cross-referencing via `\nameref`, I do not believe its functionality applies to other objects such as items of an enumerated list.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution.

Some housekeeping:

Replace

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\enumalphalphcnt{enumi})}
```

with

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\enumalphalphcnt*)}
```

or

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\enumalphalphcnt*), ref={\thesubsection(\enumalphalphcnt*)}}
```

Note that you can also say

```
\begin{enumerate}[start=27]
```

and

```
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
```

But this is not yet right because you do not want `0`s when the reference is not within a section or subsection...