# Referring to a label: how to change the name?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I define a basic hypothesis called "Hyp A", using theorem environment,
and also give it a label (say Hyp_A).

Then when I refer to this hypothesis, how to display something like "Let X and G satisfy Hyp A...", where "Hyp A" should link to the original definition of this hypothesis?

My method is as follow.

```
\newtheorem*{hyp}{} %I don't want the counter.

\begin{hyp} [\textbf{Hyp A}] \label{Hyp_A}

...

\end{hyp}

\nameref{Hyp_A}
```

Then I can have the following:

[image]

I don't like that parenthesis for the consistency reason.

Does any have suggestion to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Contrary to what you say, you *do* want the number! Just change its representation to be alphabetic: `\newtheorem{hyp}{Hyp}` and `\renewcommand{\thehyp}{\Alph{hyp}}`. Now `Hyp~\ref{Hyp_A}` will do.

Comment: If you want to have \ref return names instead of numbers, that can be done too (just not using \label).

Comment: @JohnKormylo, Thanks, but what's your meaning of "just not using \label"?

Comment: @egreg Thanks! It is helpful for me. Instead of comment, I use \newtheorem{hyp}{} and \renewcommand{\thehyp}{Hyp \thehyp}. Then \ref{Hyp_A} works well.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236626/refer-to-the-name-of-an-equation-while-a-list-of-equations-is-generated-using/236679?s=24|0.1730#236679 .  The hyperref version is slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than manually numbering the environments, you should simply change the related counter's representation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{hyp}{Hyp}
\renewcommand{\thehyp}{\Alph{hyp}}

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}\label{hyp-flat}
The Earth is flat.
\end{hyp}

Assuming Hyp~\ref{hyp-flat} we now prove that pigs can fly.

\end{document}
```

There's also the possibility of using `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{hyp}{Hyp}
\renewcommand{\thehyp}{\Alph{hyp}}
\crefname{hyp}{Hyp}{Hyp} % always uppercase       

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}\label{hyp-flat}
The Earth is flat.
\end{hyp}

Assuming \cref{hyp-flat} we now prove that pigs can fly.

\end{document}
```

[image]