# List of Equations with actual equation instead of reference

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to create something like this:

[image]

I have seen solutions in which the list of equations creates a list of the references to the equations, but how can I get to display the actual equations in the list?

Here is a sample of code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany]{book}

%packages
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \graphicspath{{images/}}
  \usepackage{float}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
  \newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}
  \usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[R]{}
  \fancyhead[L]{}
  \fancyhead[C]{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \usepackage{appendix}
  \usepackage{listings}
  \usepackage{color}

  % BOX around the answers
  \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

  % Hyperlinks and contents panel
  \usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}

  \definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122,0.435,0.698}

  % Define the box
  \newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1,width=0.5\textwidth}

  % Redefine the plain page style
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
  }



\begin{document}
%TITLE PAGE
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering

        {\scshape\LARGE Title of Document\par}


        \vfill

      % Bottom of the page
        {\large \today\par}
    \end{titlepage}

% TABLES OF CONTENT
  \tableofcontents

  \listoffigures

  \listoftables

% Body of the document
%Chapter 1
\chapter{Fundamentals of Fluid Flow in Porous Media}
\section{Calculation of Pressures Beyond the Wellbore with the Line Source Solution}

    A well and reservoir have the following characteristics. The well is producing only oil at a constant rate of 20 STB/D. The following data describe the well and formation.

    \begin{flalign*}
      && q &= 20 \text{ STB/D}&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
      && h &= 150 \text{ ft}\\
      && B &= 1.475 \text{ RB/STB} \\
      && r_e &= 3000 \text{ ft} \\
      && p_i &= 3000 \text{ psia}  \\
      && \phi &= 0.23 \\
      && c_t &= 1.5 \times 10^{-5} \text{ psi}^{-1}\\
      && \mu &= 0.72 \text{ cp}\\
      && r_w &= 0.5 \text{ ft} \\
      && k &= 0.1 \text{ md} \\
    \end{flalign*}

    Calculate the reservoir pressure at a radius of 1 ft after 3 hours of production; then, calculate the pressure at radii of 10 and 100 ft after 3 hours of production.\newline

    \textbf{Solution}\newline
    To calculate the pressure in the reservoir with the $Ei(-x) $ approximation, the line source solution equation (eq. \ref{linsource}) is used


    \begin{equation}\label{linsource}
    p = p_i + 70.6\frac{qB\mu}{kh}Ei\left(-\frac{948\phi \mu c_tr^2}{kt}\right)
    \end{equation}

    In order to apply the line source solution, the conditions per equation \ref{lincon} must be met.

    \begin{equation}\label{lincon}
    \frac{\left(3.975 \times 10^5\right) \phi \mu c_t r^{2}_w}{k} < t < \frac{948 \phi \mu c_t r^{2}_e}{k}
    \end{equation}

    Equation \ref{lincon} simplifies to
    \[2.453 \text{ hours} < t < 211.935 \text{ hours}\]
    Therefore, the $Ei(-x)$ approximation can be applied for $t=3$ hours. By substituting the value of $r$ for the different cases using eq. \ref{linsource}, the pressure values are calculated as shown in table \ref{table:1}. Note that while Lee, Rollins and Spivey (LRS) used a table to look up the values of $Ei(-x)$, the value can be easily calculated with currently available programs such as Matlab or Python.

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Reservoir Pressure at 3 Hours of Production with $Ei(-x)$ Solution}
    \begin{tabular}{|c | c | c|}
    \hline
    $r$ (ft) & Pressure (psia) & Pressure From LRS Book (psia)\\
    \hline\hline
    1 & 2572.34 & 2573\\
    10 & 2968.09 & 2968\\
    100 & 3000.00 & 3000\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:1}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that within the document body, an `equation` is set within the entire `\linewidth`. You seem to request it be set in something smaller than that in your List of Equations. How would you handle equations that fit in the document body, but not the List of Equations?

Comment: Additionally, could you provide us with a complete, minimal example that contains some equations... something we can work with. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, allowing us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and have a functional replication of your current setup.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a portion of the code. Please forgive my newbie styling

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236626/refer-to-the-name-of-an-equation-while-a-list-of-equations-is-generated-using/237126?s=1|1.5593#237126  and replace the name with `$\displaystyle ...$`.  You might want to create a new environment (environ package) so you don't have to enter the text twice.