# Multicols & enumerate inside equation

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, amsmath, multicol, enumitem

In the following MWE, how can I enclose the boxed content inside an equation environment so that I can refer to it later by its equation number?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools,multicol,blindtext,enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
    \item\label{itm:1} $a = b$,
    \item\label{itm:2} $c = d$,
    \item\label{itm:3} $e = f$,
    \item\label{itm:4} $g = h$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to leave room for the equation number, you would need to put the \multicols inside a minipage or use \llap.  I would use an array instead of multicols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses an array to display the 4 sub-equations.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools,multicol,blindtext,enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}\label{name}
  \begin{array}{cc@{\qquad}cc}
    (1) & a=b & (3) & e=f\\
    (2) & c=d & (4) & g=h
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

I took a few liberties with the subequation format, and introduced the command `\subeq` to simplify the code.

Interestingly, equation does not like have more than one `\label` inside, hence `\extralabel`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools,multicol,blindtext,enumitem}

\newcounter{subequation}[equation]
\renewcommand{\thesubequation}{\theequation\text{\alph{subequation}}}

\let\extralabel=\label
\newcommand{\subeq}[1]% #1 = label
  {\bgroup\refstepcounter{subequation}\extralabel{#1}\egroup(\thesubequation)}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}\label{name}
  \begin{array}{cc@{\qquad}cc}
    \subeq{itm:1} & a=b & \subeq{itm:2} & e=f\\
    \subeq{itm:3} & c=d & \subeq{itm:4} & g=h
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should have stated more clearly that I need to reference the individual items as well, not just the equation as a whole (which is why they are labeled in my MWE). Is this possible in your implementation?

Comment: Using a new counter is problematic as they would be number 1 2\\3 4 instead of 1 3\\2 4.  OTOH, one can use \mylabel from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236626/refer-to-the-name-of-an-equation-while-a-list-of-equations-is-generated-using/237126?s=1|34.3925#237126 and not use counters.

Comment: The numbering scheme is irrelevant as long as the individual items can be referenced.

Comment: If I use the `cleveref` and setup `\crefname{cond}{condition}{conditions}`, is there any way I can pass the optional argument `[cond]` to `extralabel`? `\let\condlabel=\label[cond]` doesn't work.

Comment: cleverref redefines \label to have a new optional argument.  If the redefinition occurs BEFORE \let\extralabel=\label, no problem.  If it uses \AtBeginDocument, you might need to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! `\AtBeginDocument{\let\extralabel=\label}` did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the subequations should be numbered in a different way (with letters, for instance) and referenced with a link to the global number.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\let\sublabel\ltx@label
\newcounter{subeq}
\renewcommand{\thesubeq}{\alph{subeq}}
\renewcommand{\p@subeq}{\theequation.}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\subeq}{\refstepcounter{subeq}\textnormal{(\thesubeq)}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}\label{foo}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setcounter{subeq}{0}
\begin{array}{
  @{}
  >{$}c<{$}>{\displaystyle}l
  @{\qquad}
  >{$}c<{$}>{\displaystyle}l
  @{}
}
\subeq\sublabel{itm:1} & a = b, &
\subeq\sublabel{itm:2} & c = d, \\
\subeq\sublabel{itm:3} & e = f, &
\subeq\sublabel{itm:4} & g = h.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\eqref{itm:1}, \eqref{itm:4}, \eqref{foo} and 
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]