# Equation-like references to text?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, text

I love labeling equations and using `\eqref{label}`.

Sometimes I miss ability to do exactly the same (create (N) side-label and reference it afterwards) with text. I mean achieving effect like

```
… therefore we conclude that sth and sth else …       (3)

(much later) ……. because of (3) …
```

When the text is short, sth like

```
\begin{align}
\text{blah blah}  \label{sth}
\end{align}
```

works almost well (sans alignment) but it's difficult to make it work with multiline text.

Is it possible to achieve this somehow? My ideal solution would be simply sth like

```
blah blah blah blah … \makeeqlikelabel{sth}
```

Comment: Where do you want to print the label when you use `\makeeqlikelabel`? Just inline with the text? In the margin? Flush right? You can always place your `\text{blah blah}` inside a `\parbox{.8\linewidth}{blah blah...}`...

Comment: If you just want to set the label inline, you can try with `\newcommand{\makeeqlikelabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}\mbox{(\theequation)}\label{#1}}`...

Comment: \label stores the value produced by the last \refstepcounter, so one way to do this is to create a new counter.  Another is to use something like \mylabel from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236626/refer-to-the-name-of-an-equation-while-a-list-of-equations-is-generated-using/237126?r=SearchResults&s=1|31.9510#237126  A third is to set `\@currentlabel`.

Comment: I'd like to place it similarly to equation labels, so it is consistent. So this probably means reducing width for current paragraph or sth like that. Also, I prefer using the same counter which equations use.