# More labels inside an equation

Tags: hyperref, labels, cleveref, auxiliary-files, autonum

I am trying to add more labels to an equation. I want to refer to the text in the equation and to the equation separately. The code has to fit the following preamble (I have a solution that has some problem with `hypertexnames=false` in the `hyperref` package and with the `autonum` package)

```
\documentclass[reqno,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor=citegreen,%
linkcolor=refred,urlcolor=blue, unicode,psdextra,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}
\section{prova}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:label}
    f(x)=a\qquad \text{\labeltext{This text}{text:label}}
\end{equation}
\cref{text:label} 
\end{document}
```

I would like to print "This text" when `\cref{text:label}` is invoked. I tried writing on the `.aux` file using `\newlabel`, but I can not use it with the above packages and options.

Comment: If what you want to print is the literal "This text", you can just define `\newcommand{\mytext}{This text}` and then call on `\mytext` wherever you want it to appear.

Comment: I also want the hyperlink like the classic `\cref` does.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236626/refer-to-the-name-of-an-equation-while-a-list-of-equations-is-generated-using although a solution using `\@currentlabel` might be more portable.